# How to resolve org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: mobileno

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am using Hibernate `Criteria` to get max value from column `mobileno` in my table.

But when I'm getting the result, it throws an exception

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: mobileno of:
```

My table bean properties is:

```
@Column(name="id")
private long id;

@Column(name="code")
private   String  code;


@Column(name="mobileno", updatable=true)
private   long  mobileno;
//Setters and Getters
```

Hibernate Code:

```
@Override
public long getMobile() {
    Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Data.class);     
    criteria.setProjection(Projections.max("mobileno"));        
    return  (long) criteria.uniqueResult();
}
```

where am I going wrong, how do I get the max value from my Table???

Comment: Are you querying on Data class table or are you joining Data table?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(Data.class);
c.addOrder(Order.desc("mobileno"));
c.setMaxResults(1);
return (Long)c.uniqueResult();
```

`criteria.setProjection` works weird

Answer (score 0):

Try to use HQL

```
select max(modelName.mobileno) from ModelName
```

and used setMaxResults(1).